# Can I use logistic to factorial experiment data?

Tags: logistic-regression, factorial

You can get [data from here.](http://www.statsci.org/data/oz/snails.txt)

My data is 4*3*3*2 completely randomized design experiment data. I want to model the probability of survival in terms of the stimulus variables.

---

I did logistic regression on factorial experiment dataset in SAS program.

log⁡(  ℎ/ )=
−5.9629−1.0969 ( )+1.2095 +0.2496∗
+ 0.3117( 60)+0.0117( 65.8)+0.0103( 70.5)
+0.4087(∗ 60)+0.1572(∗ 65.8)−0.2365(∗ 70.5)−0.4375( 10)+0.0177( 15)

This is the result formula that I got through "backward selection".
Is it right?

- Do I need to check the influential plot and outlier plot with this formula? This is the factorial experiment, and they experimented snails at one time. So I think checking the outlier is unnecessary. Is it right?
- With that result formula, I made some interpretations. Please check them.
  Species A has more mortality than Species B.
  The longer the exposure period, the higher the mortality rate.
  When the humidity is 60, the mortality is the highest.
  When the temperature is 10, the mortality is the highest.

With species A and long exposure period, the mortality is higher.
With species A and humidity is 60, the mortality is higher.

---

```
PROC GENMOD DATA=snail;
CLASS SPECIES EXPOSURE HUM TEMP;
MODEL DEATHS/N=SPECIES|EXPOSURE|HUM|TEMP / DIST=BIN LINK=LOGIT OBSTATS 
   TYPE3 P R ;
RUN;

/*BACKWARD*/
PROC LOGISTIC DATA=snail DESCENDING;
CLASS SPECIES HUM TEMP;
MODEL DEATHS/N=SPECIES|EXPOSURE|HUM|TEMP/SELECTION=BACKWARD  LINK=LOGIT;
RUN;
```

Comment: Backward selection on a designed experiment analyzed with interaction models looks sounds so wrong statistically. Not sure what you mean by "outlier" in this context. The outcome is apparently binomial.Suspect you will get better answers a CrossValidated.com, so I am nominating for migration.

Comment: Why do you think the interaction model looks wrong? What is the problem??

Comment: I think it's wrong statistically to use backward selection on a designed experiment.